# Access parents variables in Python

Tags: python, class, parent

I have something like this:

```
class SomeObject:
    #code to access parents MyVar

class MyClass:
    MyVar = 3

    MyObject = SomeObject()
```

I need to access `MyVar` from inside `MyObject`. Is there any way I can do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store a reference to the MyClass object in the SomeObject. You can initialise the reference when you make an constructor with a MyClass Object as parameter.

```
class SomeObject:
    def __init__(self, reference):
         self.reference_=reference
    #code to access parents MyVar
    self.reference_.MyVar=5

class MyClass:
    MyVar = 3

    MyObject = SomeObject(self)
```

As unutbu stated my code was not running, therefore a more detailed example.

```
class SomeObject:
    def __init__(self):
         self.reference_=None

    def connect(self, reference):
        self.reference_=reference
    #code to access parents MyVar
    def call(self):
        self.reference_.MyVar=5

class MyClass:
    MyVar = 3
    MyObject = SomeObject()
    def connect(self):
        self.MyObject.connect(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myclass = MyClass()
    myclass.connect()
    myclass.MyObject.call()
    print(myclass.MyVar)
```

Comment: I think `self` needs to be changed to `MyClass`, since `self` is not defined at this point in the definition of `MyClass`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store a reference to your parent, but you can make that magic happen automatically:

```
from weakref import ref

class MyClass(object):
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self.__dict__[key] = value
        try:
            value._parent = ref(self)
        except AttributeError:
            raise TypeError('MyClass cannot have children of type ' +
                            type(value).__name__)
    def __delattr__(self, key):
        v = self.__dict__[key]
        del self.__dict__[key]
        try:
            v._parent = None
        except AttributeError:
            raise TypeError('Child of MyClass is mysteriously '
                            'missing its parent')

class SomeObject(object):
    _parent = None
    @property
    def parent(self):
        if self._parent is not None:
            return self._parent()
        return None

>>> a = MyClass()
>>> a.b = SomeObject()
>>> print a.b.parent
<__main__.MyClass at 0x8ce60f0>
>>> b = a.b
>>> del a.b
>>> print b.parent
None
```

By overriding the `__setattr__` and `__delattr__` operators you can control the child's view of its parent and make sure that the connection is always correct.  Furthermore, this avoids using clumsy `add`/`remove` methods; methods you may accidentally forget to use. This restricts your objects to having *exactly* one parent, but for these types of models, that is generally desirable.

Lastly, I recommend that rather than holding a reference to the parent object directly, you hold a weak reference.  This avoids cyclic references that *may* confuse the garbage collector (`a` holds a reference to `b`, which holds a reference to `a`.  Their reference count never goes to 0, so they aren't garbage collected).

Comment: This is very clumsy and bad solution. Anyway, I thing op wants MyObject to be static.

Comment: i found it to be an enlightening solution and it works perfectly for what i need to do; programmatically add additional classes to my parent based on values decoded in the subclass